# Create closed room meshes

Tags: python, mesh

I have lots of imported building geometries and need a method to create simple closed inner room volumes. The buildings consists out of walls, windows slabs and so on and often they are not entirely closed. For example there might be open doors. The rooms should be as simple as possibly. Any ideas how to do this is Blender/python?

Comment: Hello, it depends a lot on your input data, could you add a bit more information about what you have now ?

Comment: The input is usually IFC-files from Revit or ArchiCAD but it could also be pure geometries.

Comment: You might want to explore topologic then https://github.com/wassimj/TopologicSverchok

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Topologic is probably the way to go but I have not been able to use it for this purpose, even with a lot of help from the author.